# Filling GridView in javascript is not working and no error catched

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

ok I am trying to fill an asp GridView using javascript. The webService call has succeeded and I can retrieve data normally. But when I want to display it in my Grid nothing happens.

Javascript Functions:

```
function SearchUsers() {
   AutoComplete.ShowLoginUserOnSearch("PL", "pi", "", "", "", 0, 20, onGetLoginUserSuccess);
  }

function onGetLoginUserSuccess(result) {
    alert(result[1].ProviderName);
    $("#grdvUserInfo").append("<tr><td>" + result[1].UserName +
           "</td><td>" + result[1].ProviderName + "</td></tr>");
    alert(result[1].UserName);
}
```

Asp.net:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdvUserInfo"  AllowPaging="True" PagerSettings-
 Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"  PageSize="20" runat="server" 
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="700px" SkinID="grdMySite" 
 DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">

</asp:GridView>
```

Both alerts are filled with the correct data, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        var customers = xml.find("Table");
        var row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
        $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
        $.each(customers, function () {
            var customer = $(this);
            $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("CustomerID").text());
            $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("ContactName").text());
            $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("City").text());
            $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
            row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
        });
    }
<script>
```

**Web Method**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCustomers()
{
    string query = "SELECT top 10 CustomerID, ContactName, City FROM Customers";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    return GetData(cmd).GetXml();
}
private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-ASPNet-GridView-by-binding-DataSet-Client-Side-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdvUserInfo"  AllowPaging="True" PagerSettings-
     Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"  PageSize="20" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="700px" SkinID="grdMySite" 
     DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">

    </asp:GridView>
```

Function

```
   function onGetLoginUserSuccess(result) {
        alert(result[1].ProviderName);
        $("#grdvUserInfo").append("<asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate>" + result[1].UserName +
               "</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate>" + result[1].ProviderName + 
"</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>");
        alert(result[1].UserName);
    }
```

Comment: Table can never be nested in gridView !